# Why did the US and UK choose different solutions to the problem of an undemocratic upper house?

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, congress, parliament, history

Both the US and the UK formerly had an upper legislative house which wielded considerable power despite being elected by government officials rather than the people (the [Senate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Senate#History)) or completely unelected (the [House of Lords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Lords)).  In the early 1900s, both countries took actions to rectify this problem, but in radically different ways; the Senate was [made directly elected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventeenth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution), while the House of Lords was [stripped of essentially all of its powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parliament_Act_1911).

Why the great difference?

Comment: Why is an unelected upper house neccecarily a problem?

Comment: In 1900, the upper house in the UK was not chosen by officials, for the most part it was hereditary. Most of its members had inherited their title from their father.

Comment: @Caleth "not democratic", "will of the people" etc

Comment: I rather like that the members of the House of Lords sit because they feel it's their _duty_ and not because they actually sought that power.

Comment: As @Alnitak said, there is no point having a second house if it works in exactly the same way as the lower house. Sometimes it is important to have people who are working on what they believe is best overall, and not dependant on the short-term whim of the electorate.

Comment: Asking why there is a difference between two things that are not directly comparable in the first place does not make a good question.  A good question would compare the U.S. Senate to the upper chamber of another federal system, such as the Australian Senate, the Indian Rajya Sabha, or the Brazilian Federal Senate; or compare the U.K. House of Lords to the upper chamber of a non-federal system, such as the Japanese House of Councillors, the French Senate, the South African NCOP, or the Irish Seanad.

Comment: @pjc50 Sometimes **good** ideas are unpopular, and **bad** ideas *are* popular.  One of the former benefits of the House of Lords (before it became packed with career Politicians) was that it was filled with people whose wealth and prosperity was directly tied to the state of the UK and its economy, so they would vote *for* unpopular-but-necessary bills, and *against* harmful populist nonsense.  So, both of those points you make were *advantages* in the House of Lords acting as a check & balance against the "popularity contest" in the House of Commons.

Comment: @Chronocidal if we go back to the original Lords controversy over the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Budget , does that count as "popular" or "populist"? Surely *everyone* is tied to the state of the UK economy, it's just that some people are in a better position to survive economic downturns?

Comment: @pjc50 At that time, man-on-the-street might have to move from one poorly paid job to another, but the Lords faced going from wealthy to destitute, penniless, and almost unemployable - so, they were in a far more precarious position.  When the check relies on that serving their own self-interest *typically* also serves the interests of the country (popular or otherwise), the exceptions such as "in the interests of the country, we require you to pay almost 3 times as much tax as you currently do" were obviously going to cause friction.

Comment: @Chronocidal I'm not really buying this "democracy is bad because losing wealth is worse than never having it in the first place" argument, but I also think it's gone far off topic.

Comment: @pjc50 My point is not quite that "democracy is bad", but rather that both systems are flawed.  However, by being flawed in *different ways* they are more likely to block each other from doing anything excessively stupid.  If you have 2 near-identical filters, then that has *very* little benefit over just having 1 filter (e.g. abolishing the upper house, and having solely the lower house) - but, yes, whether an unelected upper house is a problem or a benefit would probably be separate question.

Answer (score 14):

The two contexts are very different. The US is federal with the Senators representing the states at the federal level, while the UK was an entirely centralized state running an empire from Westminster.

The UK conflict over the budget which led to the Parliament act was effectively class warfare (with Winston Churchill on the *progressive* side!). Changing the structure altogether would probably have been out of the question. The US has a formal constitutional reform process, the UK does not; the compromise was only achieved by threatening to get the King to stuff the Lords with enough new Peers to vote it through.

(To me the part of the US system which matches the Lords most closely is actually the Supreme Court; significant power to make social change, but life appointments, and the only way to achieve democratic control is to appoint more people from a faction.)

Perhaps a more important question is why, given how often it's been in the Labour manifesto, the abolition of the Lords hasn't yet happened.

Comment: "The US has a formal constitutional reform process, the UK does not" - Though to be fair, the UK doesn't have a constitution. Shouldn't that have made reform easier?

Comment: @sgf No: the UK is based on precedent, tradition, custom, practice, general understanding, Erskine May and a number of other collections of rules and procedures. Amending a *single concrete document* is easy by comparison.

Comment: @sgf Yes and no; the UK can pass what in any other country would be constitution-level changes with a simple majority (e.g. Fixed Term Parliaments Act); but in this case, the Lords still had their veto. So it wasn't possible to make changes to the Lords without their consent. This made it a question of *realpolitic* and finding a compromise which the Lords accepted - in this case losing power over the budget and manifesto items, but not general legislation.

Comment: @pjc50 I see. I suppose that also answers your question why Labour hasn't abolished the House of Lords yet, right?

Comment: @sgf the UK has an *uncodified* constitution.

Comment: @sgf well, they haven't got a definitive replacement proposal in place and seem unwilling to commit to full abolition. I don't think the Lords would stop a coherent, fair, manifesto commitment to reform (Parliament Act), including abolition - but that particular fight hasn't been picked yet. The UK generally is bad at thinking about constitutional issues and avoids them as long as possible (see Brexit fiasco)

Comment: Also be aware that there was a consultation (including indicative votes) on reforming the HoL back in (I want to say early 2000s?) and not one of the proposals got a positive result on the indicative votes - hence we stayed with the status quo.

Comment: Abolishing the House of Lords has the same status in the Labour manifesto as "taking back key industries into public ownership" (i.e. renationalizing water and energy supplies, the railways, telecoms, etc, etc.). They keep the hard left and anti-establishment elements of the party happy, but nobody with any real political authority (except possibly Corbyn, in recent times) takes them any more seriously than the existence of the tooth fairy.

Comment: @sgf "UK Doesn't have a constitution" - more accurately, it doesn't have a written constitution; but that doesn't mean [it doesn't have one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_United_Kingdom)

Answer (score 5):

Because the UK simply couldn't have followed the US approach.

The US Senate was still quite young and democracy the official form of government, so these reforms were made easily.

In the UK however, the House of Lords was old, entrenched in tradition and - given that the official head of state is still the queen - removing the lords from the government would have brought a huge uproar among the influential (many of which held titles and were therefore on the "losing side" of this reform), so they did the most they could reasonably achieve: strip all the power while on paper retaining their title and (some) function

Comment: King, at the time, not Queen.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The whole idea of the Lords (much like the King/Queen), being drawn from a small group of people who inherited the privilege, is beyond fixing in any Democratic way. The only possible solution is to remove its power and leave it a vestigial body (like T-Rex arms). The US Senate didn't have that problem because the country didn't have explicitly hereditary social classes.

Comment: @T.E.D. It very much did, though.  Social class is generally not tied to how rich you are, but to how rich your *parents* are, because that dictates who you grow up socialising with.  Absent complete mismanagement, rich people tend to get richer, so this is self-reinforcing. It's no accident that all the Founding Fathers were wealthy, the majority being large-scale landowners.  The lack of inherited social class is one of the myths the US tells itself which every visitor can see is clearly false.

Comment: @Graham the US did not (and does not) have legally-codified hereditary social classes, except (particularly at the time) "race".

Comment: @Graham - That's a lot of words you wrote, just to explain to everyone why I used the word "explicitly".

Comment: @T.E.D. But you've fallen into the trap of thinking *the US Senate didn't have that problem*.  The US was founded by a small group of people who *inherited the privilege*.  Just because they took the name tag off that privilege, it doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: @Deolater Nor does the UK, at least not since Cromwell administered a haircut.  It has legally-codified hereditary *roles*, for sure.  But your class was (and is) a separate issue.  And those roles weren't set in stone for all time - each new generation found new people from their (ruling) class to join them in administering the country.

Comment: @Graham - Again, you're horribly misreading what I'm saying.

Comment: @Graham no. It is NOT there as with the british nobility.
 Specially because it depended on upbringing & parents wealth etc and was NOT formalized/explicit. A british family with a title could completely fall in wealth, behavior and upbringing, and STILL would have the (legal/titular) status. In the US they did not. Also one could rise from class to class without intervention from the top, just by (your parents) trying your (their) best and a bit of luck. However you don't become a lord with just good upbringing

Comment: @Hobbamok No, you became a lord by being rich and having the right kind of friends, the same as getting political power in the US.  As for rising from class to class, you're telling me that the American "old money" didn't (and don't) look down on the newly-rich millionaires?  There's plenty of literature to disprove that.  Like I said, social class is about how rich your *parents* were.  You're correct that a title sticks around regardless though, but generally if you're rich then you have to try pretty hard to lose that much money, so it's less common.

Comment: @Graham and that's exactly what T.E.D and I are saying here all the time: the US didn't have EXPLICIT heredietary classes

Comment: @Hobbamok Which is a straw man I never raised.  I know full well that the US doesn't have lords and dukes and so on.  But you both keep saying that just because there are no hereditary titles, no upper class with hereditary privilege existed or currently exists, and therefore the problem of hereditary privilege never existed.  That is patently false, because inherited money is inherited privilege, and there are many examples of upper-class US families with this inherited privilege.  The Kennedy and Bush families are the most obvious, of course, but it's trivially easy to find more.

Comment: @Graham and THAT is "a straw [we] never raised" we merely said that since there is/was no EXPLICIT (!) upper class (explicit as in a formal title) the US Senate had to fear far less pushback, since without a formal title there was no paperwork formally defining who was "fit" for the senate and who wasn't, in contrast to the UK, where such laws existed and had a long tradition.
THAT is what we're talking about here, no-one cares about any other hereditary  priviledge or whatever, go back to you social studies class.

Comment: You COMPLETELY forgot / ignored the context in which we talked here.
I know that the US is far from a clean democracy (I mean '16 would've almost been the 5th or so Bush v Clinton election), but THAT DOESN'T MATTER HERE

Answer (score 2):

The US & the UK are two different polities with different histories. It’s not particularly surprising that they have different constitutional arrangements.

The key principle in the UK is the sovereignty of parliament and this is taken to mean that government is driven by the House of Commons where the legislature is directly elected. The House of Lords then effects oversight.

Its the same rationale that means that the US congress is bicameral, that is a legislative body that has two houses.

Answer (score 1):

In the United States, the Senate exists to give small states more influence and counteract the greater population of the larger states.  It is constitutionally enshrined in that role.  At the time that the Senate was made directly elected, there was little support for reducing that role, particularly among small states.  And remember, constitutional amendments require two thirds of the Senators to agree (or a constitutional convention, but that has never happened since the founding).

In the United Kingdom, the House of Lords was left over from a time when the lords had more power.  The general trend has been to reduce that power.  When support for reduction reached a sufficient level, it was done.  Power switched from the House of Lords to the Commons.

In both cases, the change from unelected to elected would seem to be something of a side effect.  First, the Senate was appointed by the democratically elected state legislatures.  There were accusations of corruption in that process.  Direct elections were considered less corrupt rather than more democratic.  Second, the Lords were the legacy branch and the Commons the newer branch.  Transferring power from the legacy to the newer branch is natural.  It's merely an extension of the initial process.

The House of Lords did not exist because the Commons needed balanced.  It would be more accurate to say that the Commons came into existence to balance the power of the lords.

The US solution, making Senators directly elected, would have made little sense in the UK.  Rather than a natural change, it would have essentially eliminated the House of Lords and added a new House.  But how would such a House have worked?  There doesn't seem to be a movement in the UK to balance large population areas with small population areas.  So what they would have had would have been essentially a second House of Commons, which would have been redundant.

**TL;DR**:  while it is accurate to say that both switched from unelected to elected, the reasons behind the switches were quite different.

Comment: The 17th Amendment was also brought about because some of the State Legislatures could not get any candidate through, especially if a party didn't hold both houses, which does happen often.  There were several states that went for the better part of a term without filling the seats.  Corruption had little to do with this aspect and provided more of the reason to give it to direct elections.